# Angular: no HTML emojis?

Tags: html, angular

I try to use HTML emoji characters in an Angular project.

My component is

```
@Component({
selector: "mycomp",
template: `
<p>I will display &#x1F396;</p>
<p style="font-family: Arial;">I will display &#x1F396;</p>
<p style="font-familey: Symbola;">I will display &#x1F396;</p>
<p style="font-familey: Courier;">I will display &#x1F396;</p>
`
})
```

Instead of the icon (a medal) my browser (FF 68.12) only shows the symbol for an undisplayable (F39F) character.

I tried multiple font-families.

But if I have it beside the Angular project all is fine. Even if I put it outside the code-section in this question I see the icon correctly in preview with the same browser. So I think the problem might be in the Angular project.

My index.html is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wrap it with `span` tag and display with `[innerHtml]` attribute.
In your component

```
export class MyComponent{
....
symbol = '&#x1F396;'

}
```

In your html

```
<span [innerHtml]="symbol"></span>
```

Comment: Does work that way. But why is that complicated way needed??